# How to pass the PostgreSQL query result into a variable in Airflow? (Postgres Operator or Postgres Hook)

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I'm planning to use PostgreSQL as my task meta info provider, so I want to run a few queries and get some data and pass it like a filled variable to another task.
The problem is when I use **PostgresHook** I get the data but its in a python method that I cant access, in fact I see bellow line

```
[2021-08-23 13:00:12,628] {python.py:151} INFO - Done. Returned value was: [[1, "inf_account",....]]
```

here is part of my code:

```
def _query_postgres(**context):
    """
    Queries Postgres and returns a cursor to the results.
    """

    postgres = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="aramis_postgres_connection")
    conn = postgres.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    mark_williams = cursor.execute(" SELECT * FROM public.aramis_meta_task; ")

    # iterate over to get a list of dicts
    details_dicts = [doc for doc in cursor]

    # serialize to json string
    details_json_string = json.dumps(details_dicts, default=json_util.default)

    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="my_value", value=details_json_string)
    return details_json_string
```

but I don't know which variable should I use to access it or how to push it to XCOM so that i can use that returned value as a parameter to another bashoperator task(Spark for example).

**PostgresOperator** on the other hand, only returns `None` as result.

Comment: which version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: @jdimella latest, version 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick behind [`XComs`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) is that you `push` them in one task and `pull` it in another task. If you want to use the `XCom` you pushed in the `_query_postgres` function in a bash operator you can use something like this:

```py
puller = BashOperator(
        task_id="do_something_postgres_result",
        bash_command="some-bash-command {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='my_value', task_ids='query_postgres_task_id_here') }}",
        dag=dag)
```

You will need to replace the `bash_command` with the appropriate one, and change the `task_ids` from the `xcom_pull()` to set the `task_id` from the task you created that invokes the `_query_postgres` function.

Regarding `PostgresOperator`, it's okay that returns `None`. It's not meant for data extraction (even if you run a `SELECT` query. The way you implemented that with the `PostgresHook` is okay.

Some good sources to understand `XComs`:

1. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/airflow-tricks-xcom-and-subdag-361ff5cd46ff
2. https://precocityllc.com/blog/airflow-and-xcom-inter-task-communication-use-cases/
3. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py

Comment: I actually have no problem with accessing it in bash environment, your code "something like this" actually was the answer. voted, TY

Comment: Great. You can also mark the question as answered to help others as well :)

Comment: of course, I wait for a week or 2 and do check-mark your answer. :)

Comment: You can also upvote the question if it was a good question in your point of view and helping the community.

Answer (score 2):

The PostgresOperator does not return any values, so unfortunately you can't use that to pass around data. You'll have to implement your own operator, for which you can indeed use the PostgresHook.

There are a few things to note about your code:

1. The "Returned value was" log is output from the PythonOperator?
2. You can "explicitly" push to XCom which you showed with `xcom_push()`, but returning a value also automatically pushes to XCom, so you'll have your output stored in XCom twice.
3. You can "pull" an XCom value using `xcom_pull()`, more details here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html
4. You can fetch all output from the Postgres cursor using `cursor.fetchall()`, I have a similar example here (it writes output to local disk): https://github.com/godatadriven/airflow-testing-examples/blob/master/src/testing_examples/operators/postgres_to_local_operator.py#L35-L41
5. Be careful with large data & XComs. By default, XComs are stored in the Airflow metastore, and you don't want to store data in there that's too big. Alternatively, you can configure a custom XCom backend which allows you to use e.g. AWS S3 for XCom storage: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/custom-xcom-backends

Comment: Thanks for your response, have you tried this with other databases like redis? im considering doing so with other DBs.